# Show urls o/p in iframe

Tags: drupal, view

i am using feeds module for import news items.By using views,i display the news title,description and item url.In this,when user hit the item urls means its loads that particular site inside my site.I try to use Iframe by way of "output rewrite option" in views.But that page load fully instead of load inside my site.I use following code for that.

```
<iframe src="[url]" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>[url]</p>
</iframe>
```

Any one please guide me resolve this.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the `target` attribute on an `a` tag. For example when the user hit's the item URL it would load in the target window which in this case is the frame. Take for example the code below.

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" target="target_frame">test</a>
<iframe name="target_frame" src="http://www.google.com" frameborder="0" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
```

The frame initially loads google.com but once the link is clicked the `target` attribute on the `a` directs the click to the frame which has the same `name` attribute, in this case `target_frame`

You can read more about the `target` attribute here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: i try to implement above code in output rewrite block in views but it wont work. <code><a href="[url]" target="target_frame">test</a>
<iframe name="target_frame" src="" frameborder="0" width="300" height="300"></iframe>
 </code> it display link in new window instead of showing o/p in iframe.is it anything i commit wrong. thanks

Comment: Can you go to view source in your browser and show what has been output? Also, use ` on each side of your text to output code rather than <code> tags.

Comment: Like you said i view the code using page view source that'<iframe name="target_frame" src="" frameborder="0" width="300" height="300"></iframe>'didn't executed if i use  tokens instead of using absolute url.if i use absolute path means that iframe come.Is there any settings i need to enable for iframes works in views?

Comment: An `iframe` will work in any template- no need to enable it. Is the URL from a field in the node your view is showing? If so, what's the field name? Also, what's the name of the template you're outputting the `iframe` in?

Comment: The url from a field is showed perfectly there is no issue in that one.The name of the field id is '[url]'.I use "Unformmatted style" (select style in basic settings)for showing output.The following code that i placed inside the output rewrite section'<a href="[url]" target="target_frame">Click Me</a>
<iframe name="target_frame" src="www.yahoo.com" frameborder="0" width="300" height="300"></iframe>'